How to handle multiple data sources with credentials when you're deploying AAS model through Azure DevOPS release pipeline
I have a tabular model with two data source connections. Both data sources connect to different servers (and databases) to retrieve data for the tables in the model. Within Azure DevOps, I have created a release pipeline to deploy the model.bim file to my Azure Analysis server using the 'Tabular Database Deployment' step.
In this step, you can specify the 'data source type'. Since I have two data sources, I selected 'Advanced (multiple connections)'. Under this field, in 'Advanced datasource security settings', I need to provide the credentials for each data source. If I don't do this and attempt to process the tables in the model, I get an error indicating that the credentials were not provided correctly.
I have two other tasks in my pipeline before the 'Tabular Database Deployment' step. One retrieves the data from my Azure Key Vault and the other is an Azure CLI task that fetches the details of my Service Connection. The 'Tabular Database Deployment' is the final step.
I have tried the following in the 'Advanced datasource security settings':
[
  {
    "type": "structured",
    "name": "TEST1",
    "connectionDetails": {
      "protocol": "tds",
      "address": {
        "server": "room1.net",
        "database": "Test_db1"
      },
      "authentication": null,
      "query": null
    },
    "credential": {
      "AuthenticationKind": "UsernamePassword",
      "kind": "SQL",
      "Username": "bla1",
      "EncryptConnection": true,
      "Password": "$(DS1_PASSWORD)"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "structured",
    "name": "TEST2",
    "connectionDetails": {
      "protocol": "tds",
      "address": {
        "server": "room2.net",
        "database": "Test_db2"
      },
      "authentication": null,
      "query": null
    },
    "credential": {
      "AuthenticationKind": "UsernamePassword",
      "kind": "SQL",
      "Username": "bla2",
      "EncryptConnection": true,
      "Password": "$(DS2_PASSWORD)"
    }
  }
]

I get the following error:

Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected.

I tried everything, asked ChatGPT, etc., but I don't know what to do. I can't seem to pass the credentials through. The secret is stored in my Azure Key Vault, which is why I use the variable.
Solution: I want to process the tables from the different data sources. The credentials I pass through the Azure DevOps release pipeline must be included in my deployment.
Who can help me? It would be greatly appreciated as I'm stuck on this for a few days now.
EDIT
Full YAML of the last step, as asked by @Kevin Lu-MSFT
steps:
- task: liprec.vsts-release-aas.deploy-aas-db.deploy-aas-db@1
  displayName: 'blabla1'
  inputs:
    connectedServiceNameSelector: connectedServiceNameARM
    connectedServiceNameARM: 'ppppp'
    aasServer: 'pppppp.net'
    databaseName: 'test11_tabular'
    loginType: spn
    tenantId: '$(tenantId)'
    appId: '$(servicePrincipalId)'
    appKey: '$(servicePrincipalKey)'
    pathToModel: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/aa/Model/test11_Tabular/bin/Model.asdatabase'
    partitionDeployment: deploypartitions
    roleDeployment: deployrolesandmembers
    connectionType: advanced
    datasources: |
      [
        {
          "type": "structured",
          "name": "TEST1",
          "connectionDetails": {
            "protocol": "tds",
            "address": {
              "server": "room1.net",
              "database": "Test_db1"
            },
            "authentication": null,
            "query": null
          },
          "credential": {
            "AuthenticationKind": "UsernamePassword",
            "kind": "SQL",
            "Username": "bla1",
            "EncryptConnection": true,
            "Password": "$(DS1_PASSWORD)"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "structured",
          "name": "TEST2",
          "connectionDetails": {
            "protocol": "tds",
            "address": {
              "server": "room2.net",
              "database": "Test_db2"
            },
            "authentication": null,
            "query": null
          },
          "credential": {
            "AuthenticationKind": "UsernamePassword",
            "kind": "SQL",
            "Username": "bla2",
            "EncryptConnection": true,
            "Password": "$(DS2_PASSWORD)"
          }
        }
      ]
    overwrite: false


Can you share more details about the Release Pipeline settings? If you are using classic release pipeline, you can export the task definition to YAML format and share with us. This will be helpful to investigate the issue further.

JSON string seems to be valid, but be aware that special characters, quotes, etc in $(DS1_PASSWORD) or $(DS2_PASSWORD) might invalidate it. It also depends on how you're trying to replace the values. As Kevin mentioned, please edit your post and add the relevant part of the pipeline in YAML format if possible.

I have provided the YAML of the last step. now in my original post

Does any of the passwords contain "?

Yes, one of them has " in the password.. just checked. But the other one don't.

@Abdio68 I can reproduce the same issue when using the password contains "". Can you check if the password contains ' if no, you can use single quote to set the password value . for example: "Password": '$(DS1_PASSWORD)'  Then you can check if it can work.

When I put the single quote to the password containing the " , then it worked. GOD DAMN haha I love debugging. days of searching for a solution lied in changing the quote. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

@Abdio68 I have recorded an answer to share the work method based on my comment above. You can check it. This will be helpful to other users who using the same task to deploy AAS model.


Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected.

As discuss with @Abdio68, the cause of the issue is that the password contains " in the content.
I can reproduce the same issue when the password contains the " character.

To solve this issue, we can use single quote to define the password value in the json object.
for example:
From
"Password": "$(DS1_PASSWORD)"

To
"Password": '$(DS1_PASSWORD)'

In this case, we can keep the correct password value in the variable and pass the json object successfully.
On the other hand, when changing passwords, we can avoid using single quote and double quotes in the password value.

As mentioned in the comments, the $(DS1_PASSWORD) and $(DS2_PASSWORD) variables might contain values that need to be escaped, such as " (double quotes).
Running a quick test using the Windows Powershell ISE:

I'd recommend to add an extra task to escape these variables into a proper json string and then use the escaped values in the liprec.vsts-release-aas.deploy-aas-db.deploy-aas-db@1 task.
Example:
variables:
  - name: DS1_PASSWORD
    value: 'my "pass$:word' # <----------- password with double quotes
  - name: DS2_PASSWORD
    value: 'my other pass:wo\rd'

steps:
  - pwsh: |
      $DS1_PASSWORD_JSON = (${Env:DS1_PASS} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress).Trim()
      $DS2_PASSWORD_JSON = (${Env:DS2_PASS} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress).Trim()

      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DS1_PASSWORD_JSON;issecret=true]$DS1_PASSWORD_JSON"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DS2_PASSWORD_JSON;issecret=true]$DS2_PASSWORD_JSON"
    displayName: Encode passwords
    env:
      # use environment variables to avoid handling special characters in the script body
      DS1_PASS: $(DS1_PASSWORD)
      DS2_PASS: $(DS2_PASSWORD)

  # use DS1_PASSWORD_JSON and DS2_PASSWORD_JSON variables 
  # instead of DS1_PASSWORD and DS2_PASSWORD
  - task: liprec.vsts-release-aas.deploy-aas-db.deploy-aas-db@1
    displayName: 'blabla1'
    inputs:
      connectedServiceNameSelector: connectedServiceNameARM
      connectedServiceNameARM: 'ppppp'
      aasServer: 'pppppp.net'
      databaseName: 'test11_tabular'
      loginType: spn
      tenantId: '$(tenantId)'
      appId: '$(servicePrincipalId)'
      appKey: '$(servicePrincipalKey)'
      pathToModel: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/aa/Model/test11_Tabular/bin/Model.asdatabase'
      partitionDeployment: deploypartitions
      roleDeployment: deployrolesandmembers
      connectionType: advanced
      datasources: |
        [
          {
            "type": "structured",
            "name": "TEST1",
            "connectionDetails": {
              "protocol": "tds",
              "address": {
                "server": "room1.net",
                "database": "Test_db1"
              },
              "authentication": null,
              "query": null
            },
            "credential": {
              "AuthenticationKind": "UsernamePassword",
              "kind": "SQL",
              "Username": "bla1",
              "EncryptConnection": true,
              "Password": "$(DS1_PASSWORD_JSON)"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "structured",
            "name": "TEST2",
            "connectionDetails": {
              "protocol": "tds",
              "address": {
                "server": "room2.net",
                "database": "Test_db2"
              },
              "authentication": null,
              "query": null
            },
            "credential": {
              "AuthenticationKind": "UsernamePassword",
              "kind": "SQL",
              "Username": "bla2",
              "EncryptConnection": true,
              "Password": "$(DS2_PASSWORD_JSON)"
            }
          }
        ]
      overwrite: false


Really appreciate for giving such a detailed instruction. I was able to fix the problem by using a single quote on the password containing a ". I'm gonna try your method now to see if this also works.

@Abdio68 careful - using single quotes might fix one issue, but what if your password contains both ' and " and/or any other characters that need to be encoded?

Ah, thanks for reminding it! We change passwords regularly so changing the quote might fix the issue on short term, but long term its a risk yeah. Im gonna try to use your method and let you know if it worked. Thanks again!

@Abdio68 and RuiJarimba  Escaping double quotes or other characters is a good idea. But in the current case, the escaped characters(e.g. additional \ character) may be added to the password content, which may cause the password to be wrong.  You can have a try the method and check if it really work. If it can work, you can keep using it.

@KevinLu-MSFT yes I see your point, but giving that the DSx_PASSWORD variables will be used as part of a json string, I don't think we have other alternatives. If we were to set an hard-coded password containing " we'd have to encode it, right?

@RuiJarimba If it is a normal json object, it is reasonable to escape the double quotes. But as a password, it may be a little special. When passing the password, it may be necessary to keep the password content unchanged.  Your method is undoubtedly good.  Another possibility I can think of is to avoid using single and double quotes when changing the password. The current limitation is mainly the quotes

@Abdio68 I just updated the sample code - you should add issecret=true when setting the pipeline variables as these contain sensitive information.

The provided solution didnt work for my Azure CLI task step in the inline script. With a few trial-and-error I managed to do it, but then Im getting the same error as before when the deployment task is done. I think the passwords are not correctly passed. I'm gonna stick to the first solution for now and will see further if the password is changed

@Abdio68 take a good look into my answer and double-check you didn't forget anything. Pipeline variables must be replaced in the json string as well (datasources property). Also, are you running all tasks in the same job?

No, i have different tasks. One for getting the secrets out of the AKV, one for getting the details of the SC and one for the deployment of the tabular model. I made an extra task for the code you provided. Checkec everything but it gave an error.

@Abdio68 but are these tasks running in the same job or not?
